# jQuery on mouse scroll go to next id

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, mousewheel

I'm trying to make a script that goes to the next id when I scroll down and to the prev one when I scroll Up.

I only got it to work with `click()` which works but I need the same code to work on `mousewheel()`

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="sidebar"> 

       <ul>
            <li><a id = "first_info" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a id = "second_info" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a id = "third_info" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a id = "fourth_info" href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a id = "fifth_info" href="#">5</a></li>
            <li><a id = "sixth_info" href="#">6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

$("#sidebar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
      // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
    e.preventDefault(); 
      // Call the scroll function
    goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));        
});
```

This is the code that works when I click on the list items and this is the code I tried to use on mouse wheel but with no success.

```
$('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {


    if (delta > 0) {
    $("#sidebar > ul > li > a").attr("id")); 
    } else {
            $("#sidebar > ul > li > a").attr("id")); 
    }

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You've omitted the `goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));` - that's the code which is telling the browser to scroll.

Comment: yes but still doesn't work. Any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
       window.location.href = "#down";
   } else {
      // upscroll code
       window.location.href = "#up";
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work on mouse scroll, only If I click on the lists. :(

Comment: yes I did but doesn't help me as I can't get it to do what I need.